# How do I pass the DOM object (this) that contains an ng-repeat statement into the ng-if function? (Javascript/AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have an ng-repeat on my page, and I need to filter the items that are in it. For the purposes of filtering I've included the hidden field above it which contains a key that I need to use.

```
<div class="filterProductsContainer">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="FilterKey"/>
    <ul class="product_listing_component--results-list">
        <li ng-if="isInCategory(product, $event)" ng-repeat="product in filterProducts">
            <a href="{{product.link}}">
                <img src="{{product.image}}" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
$scope.isInCategory = function (product, $event) {
    console.log(product);
    console.log($event);
    var filterKey = $($event.target).parent(".filterProductsContainer").find("input[type='hidden'").val();
    console.log(filterKey);
    var targetProduct = $scope.products[product];
    var foundMatch = false;
    for (var tag in targetProduct.tags) {
        var targetTag = targetProduct.tags[tag];
        if (filterKey === targetTag.id) {
            foundMatch = true;
        }

        if (foundMatch) {
            break;
        }

    }
    return foundMatch;
}
```

$event ends up being null, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the filter directly in ng-repeat

```
<li ng-repeat="product in filterProducts | filter: {id: '<FilterKeyValue>'}" >
```

Where `id` is the property name of your `product` object you want use to filter by.

Comment: How will it interpret FilterKeyValue? Where does that come from?

Comment: That's the actual value to filter by, in your case I guess it is the value of the  FilterKey hidden field. Say `filterProducts` contains `[{someProperty: '1', name: 'obj1'}, {someProperty: '2', name: 'obj2'}]` and you do this: `<li ng-repeat="product in filterProducts | filter: {someProperty: '2'}">{{product.name}}</li>` Then ng-repeat will automatically only show the product objects which have a `2` in their `someProperty` property. So in this case, you should only see an LI element containing `'obj2'`.